# Receive message from JavaScript WebView in Objective-C

Tags: javascript, ios, objective-c, ios7

I have a WebView with a JavaScript function `loadStuff`, that makes some ajax calls.

In my AppDelegate, I've managed to to use WebView's stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString to execute loadStuff.

Now my problem is I want to execute some Objective-C code once the JavaScript ajax stuff is done. How can my JavaScript notify back the native code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have access to your AJAX success handler, you can just force webview to open some fake url from it and then handle this from delegate's shouldStartLoadWithRequest.

Comment: If you can expand on your answer and write more details, it can be useful for future searches. Like code example...

Comment: Well, i'll try to introduce some code snippet. Did you solve your problem with such way?

Comment: Yes, similar to what you said I made a call to a custom protocol (nh-js://sometext) I caught the request in the delegate.

Comment: Using this article: http://blog.techno-barje.fr/post/2010/10/06/UIWebView-secrets-part3-How-to-properly-call-ObjectiveC-from-Javascript/